# svn co http:// Unable to connetc to a repository at URL

Tags: svn, ros

```
$ svn co http://pi-robot-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pi_vision
```

> Uable to connect to a repository at URL ...

I want to follow this tutorial 
http://wiki.ros.org/pi_face_tracker 
While installing pi_vision stack, I met obstacle.
How to fix it?

Comment: @San.Actually url doennot exist.

Answer (score 1):

The googlecode is closed, maybe you can try this repo:

https://github.com/hansonrobotics/pi_vision